# Use early 2009 20" iMac as external display for 2015 rMBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac, thunderbolt

I wanted to use a mini display-port cable then use "target display mode" to make the iMac an external display, but I just read that early 2009 iMac's don't have target display mode as a feature.

Anybody knows of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with your particular iMac (2009 20")

Per the [Target Display Mode System Requirements Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) it specifically says:

> A supported iMac with OS X v10.6.1 or later.

The supported iMacs are:

> - iMac (27-inch Late 2009)
> - iMac (27-inch Mid 2010)
> - iMac (Mid 2011)
> - iMac (Mid 2012-Mid 2014)

However, there is an App that allows you to turn a spare Mac into an extended monitor.  It's called [Air Display](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-display/id419449718?mt=12#).  This is *not* my ideal solution as video intensive applications don't perform well with software solutions.

If you need a secondary monitor, you may have to get a dedicated monitor to meet your needs